# Xamarin Android EditText.KeyPress vs EditText.TextChanged events

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following two event handlers for an EditText field, the first one works but the second one did not. I will rather have the second one working because the first event handler requires that the user press the enter key which I suspect not every one will do.

First and working

```
private decimal paidAmount;
private EditText EditTextPaidAmount;

 EditTextPaidAmount = RootView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextAmountPaid);
            EditTextPaidAmount.KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e) =>
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
                {
                    paidAmount = Decimal.Parse(EditTextPaidAmount.Text);
                    RenderInvoiceTotals();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            };
```

This here is not working, it throws a System.FormatException "Invalid character at position 0"

```
   EditTextPaidAmount = RootView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextAmountPaid);
            EditTextPaidAmount.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                    paidAmount = Decimal.Parse(EditTextPaidAmount.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    RenderInvoiceTotals();
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using `Decimal.TryParse` instead?

This code works for me:

```
edit.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
  decimal decimalValue;
  var isDecimal = Decimal.TryParse(edit.Text, out decimalValue);
  if (isDecimal)
    text.Text = decimalValue.ToString();
};
```

Is the exception coming from `RenderInvoiceTotals`?

Comment: Thanks, TryParse was throwing the same exception.

Comment: @Val I've updated the answer. I'm using Xamarin 3.9 and Xamarin.Android 4.20

Comment: Thanks @ Angak, it is definitely no the RenderInvioiceTotals that is throwing exception because all that method does is display text view. I applied your answer and it runs but as soon as the Text changes, it through an exception

Answer (score 0):

Set the `inputType` property of the EditText to `numberDecimal`.

OR

Use `Decimal.TryParse` to parse the EditText value.

Because the error you have mentioned usually appears due to the parsing of string values to decimal.

Comment: Thanks Nirmal, I changed the inputType property with no success.

Comment: @ValOkafor, I think, you are getting this error on text value entries in the EditText or you are getting the issue with number entries too. Because I tried the code you have mentioned, it throws the same error when entered text data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EditorAction` event

```
 EditTextPaidAmount.EditorAction += (sender, e) =>
 {
     e.Handled = false;
     if (e.ActionId == ImeAction.Send)
     {
        DoStuff();
        e.handled = true;   
     }
 };
```

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3686/edittext-setoneditoractionlistener-is-this-supported